# Solr basic authentication is not working in linux

Tags: solr, basic-authentication

I have tried adding basic authentication using the below link. It is working fine in Windows but not in Linux server.
https://javadeveloperzone.com/solr/securing-solr-setup-basic-authentication/

security.json

```
{
"authentication":{
   "blockUnknown": true,
   "class":"solr.BasicAuthPlugin",
   "credentials":{"solr":"IV0EHq1OnNrj6gvRCwvFwTrZ1+z1oBbnQdiVC3otuq0= Ndd7LKvVBAaZIF0QAVi1ekCfAJXr1GGfLtRUXhgrF8c="}
},
"authorization":{
   "class":"solr.RuleBasedAuthorizationPlugin",
   "permissions":[{"name":"security-edit",
      "role":"admin"}],
   "user-role":{"solr":"admin"}
   }

}
```

Added these line in solr.in.sh

SOLR_AUTH_TYPE="basic"
SOLR_AUTHENTICATION_OPTS="-Dbasicauth=solr:SolrRocks"

Comment: So what did you try? What files did you upload? What does your security.json file look like? Are you using standalone or cloud mode? Have you made sure that the filename is properly lowercase (since NTFS is case-insensitive, while most Linux file systems are not). You'll have to provide enough information to someone to at least have an idea what's gone wrong; "It doesn't work" doesn't really make anyone able to help you.

Comment: 1. Added security.json in place where solr.xml resides. I am using Solr stand alone. security.json is in lowercase only. Added the security.json and comments which i enabled.

Comment: Which version of Solr are you using, and what does "does not work" imply? Does it ask for authentication and it doesn't work, or does it just let everything true like the file wasn't there? Does the Solr log say anything?

Comment: Solr version -7.4.0. It is allowing everyone and no pop for credentials.

Answer (score 0):

Your security.json file and other changes seems correct . Please make sure security.json file is in correct folder